# iterating through collection - removing other element

Tags: java, collections, iterator

What do I have to do if I would like to remove not only element my iterator points now, but also another one? Task is to write out pairs that sum up to some value (they are stored in HashSet set). Idea: iterate through the set, find second element that sum to what I need, write them out and remove from set both. What I mean, if my set is: [1,2,3] and int sum = 4, then I iterate through, find element 1st: 1, check 4 - 1 = 3, write out (1,3), and then I would like to remove 1 and 3 from the set so that only {2} left. I cannot do this that way of course:

```
while (itr.hasNext()) {
  int elem = itr.next();
  int toSum = sum - elem;
  if (set.contains(toSum)) {
    System.out.println("(" + elem + "," + toSum + ")");
  }
  itr.remove();
  set.remove(toSum);
}
```

because of concurrent exception. I found out that solution:

```
while (itr.hasNext()) {
  HashSet<Integer> notNeeded = new HashSet<Integer>();
  int elem = itr.next();
  if (notNeeded.contains(elem)) {
    itr.remove();
  }
  else {
    int toSum = sum - elem;
    if (set.contains(toSum)) {
      System.out.println("(" + elem + "," + toSum + ")");
      notNeeded.add(toSum);
    }
    itr.remove();
  }
}
```

but that does not look elegant and efficient (especially space efficient). Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Since you're iterating integers, I might just make a copy of the Collection and iterate over that while modifying the original...

Comment: Why not just use a nested loop?

Comment: Thanks guys. But I must admit that I can see that your approaches are different than mine, I cannot tell if they are more sufficient in any way... do I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest a second Set with the used values. You can then decide whether to actually remove them from the original set at the end, or not.

```
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6));
int target = 7;

Set<Integer> used = new HashSet<>();
for (Integer value1 : set) {
    if (used.contains(value1))
        continue; // already processed
    Integer value2 = target - value1;
    if (! value2.equals(value1) && set.contains(value2)) {
        used.add(value1);
        used.add(value2);
        System.out.println("(" + value1 + "," + value2 + ")");
    }
}
set.removeAll(used); // optional
```

By making it nondestructive, you can reuse the Set for other searches:

```
private static void listPairs(Set<Integer> set, int target) {
    System.out.print(target + ": ");
    Set<Integer> used = new HashSet<>();
    for (Integer value1 : set)
        if (! used.contains(value1)) {
            Integer value2 = target - value1;
            if (! value2.equals(value1) && set.contains(value2)) {
                used.add(value1);
                used.add(value2);
                System.out.print("(" + value1 + "," + value2 + ")");
            }
        }
    System.out.println();
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6));
    listPairs(set, 7);
    listPairs(set, 6);
    listPairs(set, 5);
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
7: (1,6)(2,5)(3,4)
6: (1,5)(2,4)
5: (1,4)(2,3)
```

Comment: The only difference between your solution and mine is that you do not modify original set till the end, am I right or do I miss something?

Comment: Yeah, except that your code doesn't work because `notNeeded` is declared *inside* the loop.

Comment: Also, I guard against `(3,3)` as a result when looking for sums of `6`.

Comment: I checked it and I'm quite sure it DOES work actually. But I can see the problem of course... hmmm... I have to check it agaiin :D anyway that's not what the question was about :) Thanks for help!

Comment: You're right. So set is not the best idea here. The point was I dont want to write repeated pairs (as initially I had an array as argument). So for the input [1,2,1,2],3 the result should be (1,2) only once, not twice.

Comment: @Malvinka The reason it accidentally worked is because when you find pair `(1,3)`, you remove the `1`, so when it tries `(3,1)` is cannot find the `1` anymore. The `notNeeded` is ineffectual, since `notNeeded.contains(elem)` will always return `false` right after `notNeeded` is created. If you checked the set at the end, you'd see that `3` was never removed.

Comment: Right! So probably better idea would be to store pairs found in some set and write them out at the end... hash map solution and then set?

Comment: Why? This answer gives you what you want. No duplicates. No bad `(3,3)` answer. Can optionally leave original set intact, depending on need. Since you didn't notice that `3` wasn't removed in your version, you don't seem to need to remove used values from original set, so just don't do the unnecessary `removeAll()`.

Comment: Nope. I'm thinking about situation where initial args would be array [4,2,3,3] and we're looking for sum 6. Then the result should be (4,2) and (3,3) while in my solution I dont have second pair cause only one 3 will be in my set.

Answer (score 0):

Well, of course you cannot call `Set.remove()` from within the `Iterator` because of the concurrent exception, but you can break the iteration and remove it afterwards.

```
Integer toSumFound = null;
while (itr.hasNext()) {
    int elem = itr.next();
    int toSum = sum - elem;
    if (set.contains(toSum)) {
      toSumFound = toSum;
      System.out.println("(" + elem + "," + toSum + ")");
      itr.remove();
      break;
    }
}
set.remove(toSumFound); //Check for nulls if needed
```